# What is the difference between prospective, contingent and tentative offer?

Tags: meaning, differences, business-language, legalese

What is the difference between prospective, contingent and tentative offer?

Can you make some sentences using the word prospective for better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

**prospective offer** is very positive phrase. Yo can use it when you are advertising something.

**contingent offer** is used when you want to set limitations on an offer you make.

**tentative offer** can be used when you are going to suggest something but you are not certain about that.

Comment: Fine. Could you mention them in 3 different sentences as to including the situation for better understanding?